# How to modify / edit an installed anaconda package

Tags: python, git, github, anaconda, package

I have some issues with a published package and wish to edit the code myself (may generate a pull request later to contribute). I am quite confused about how to do this since it seems there is a lack of step-by-step guidance. Could anybody give me a very detailed instruction about how this is done (or a link)? My understanding and also my questions about the workflow are:

1. Fork the package through git/github and have a local synced copy (done!).
2. Create a new Anaconda environment (done!)?
3. Install the package as normal: $conda install xxx or $python setup.py develop?
4. Do I make changes to the package directly in the package folder in Anaconda if I use python setup.py develop?
5. Or make changes to the local forked copy and install/update again and what are the commands for this?
6. Do I need to update the setup.py file as well before running it either way?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply git-clone the package repo to your local computer and then install it in "*development*" or "*editable*" mode. This way you can easily make changes to the code while at the same time incorporating it into your own projects. Of course, this will also allow you to create pull requests later on.

Using Anaconda (or Miniconda) you have 2 equivalent options for this:

1. using *conda* ([conda-develop](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-develop.html)):

```
conda develop <path_to_local_repo>
```

2. using *pip* ([pip install options](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#options))

```
pip install --editable <path_to_local_repo>
```

What these commands basically do is creating a link to the local repo-folder inside the environments site-packages folder.

Note that for "*editable*" pip installs you need a a basic *setup.py*:

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(name=<anything>)
```

On the other hand the `conda develop <path_to_local_repo>` command unfortunately doesn't work in *environment.yml* files.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I create a new environment. I found some packages are installed in C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\fpd\Lib\site-packages, some in C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\python\Python310\site-packages. The package I want to change is in the 2nd directory. The original forked package is saved in fold A and I do see a conda.pth file pointing to folder A. Do you mean if I chance code in fold A and the package in the 2nd directory will be automatically updated? But didn't see this.